# How do I edit/view android system.img files located SDK emulator images

Tags: sdk

I want to edit a few files inside android-30\google_apis_playstore system.img which resides in sdk/system-images. I'm using WSL ubuntu 18.04, I do `fdisk -lL system.img` to mount with the right offset
which returns

```
Disk system.img: 2.7 GiB, 2832203776 bytes, 5531648 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 419B5BC3-59EE-4BEA-AA53-FF67E1D7406E

Device      Start     End Sectors  Size Type
system.img1  2048    4095    2048    1M Linux filesystem
system.img2  4096 5529599 5525504  2.7G Linux filesystem
```

and by doing `sudo mount -t auto -o ro,loop,offset=2097152 ./system.img /mnt/loop`
it fails like this

```
mount: /mnt/loop: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/loop1, missing codepage or helper program, or other error.
```

I have also tried to use `simg2img` which is said that it will convert the image to a raw image in which I can mount it which yields invalid sparse file
`simg2img system.img raw.img`

```
Invalid sparse file format at header magic
Failed to read sparse file
```

Do you have any idea of how to open or mount the system.img file and edit a few files?

Comment: guess off-topic but try *dd skip=offset count=size | simg2img* or *kpartx*. there is also *--writeable-system* flag for modifications on runtime